# How to order a vertical table by column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, select, sql-order-by

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
id | m_id | name | value
--------------------
 1 | 1    | bed  |   3
 3 | 1    | bath |   3
 2 | 2    | bed  |   4
 3 | 2    | bath |   2
```

I want to order the results using `value` and keep the `m_id` in order.

If I order by `bed DESC` from the `name` column, the result should look like this:

```
id | m_id | name | value
--------------------
 2 | 2    | bed  |   4
 3 | 2    | bath |   2
 1 | 1    | bed  |   3
 3 | 1    | bath |   3
```

If I order by `bath DESC` from the `name` column, the result should look like this:

```
id | m_id | name | value
--------------------
 1 | 1    | bed  |   3
 3 | 1    | bath |   3
 2 | 2    | bed  |   4
 3 | 2    | bath |   2
```

No matter if the `name` order changes, I only care that `m_id` stays in order.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you use ORDER BY value, m_id?

Comment: because the `m_id` doesn't stay in order

Comment: I think you can use something like: select id,m_id,name,value from table order by m_id,value

Comment: What does `ORDER BY bed DESC` mean? `bed` isn't a column name, it's the value in some rows.

Comment: You say you want to keep `m_id` in order. Why is `m_id` ascending in the first result, but descending in the second result?

Comment: I DON'T UNDERSTAND YOUR QUESTION! ARGHHHHH... (is this SQL anymore?)

Comment: By `in order` I mean `1, 1, 2, 2` and not `1, 2, 1, 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the `order by`.  This is sort of cool:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (select max(t2.value) from t t2 where t2.m_id = t.m_id) desc, m_id;
```

Of course, this can be done more traditionally using `join` and `group by`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t2.m_id, max(t2.value) as max_value
      from t t2
      group by t2.m_id
     ) t2
     on t.m_id = t2.m_id
order by t2.max_value desc, m_id;
```

Comment: You deciphered what he wants from that question? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, since I can't really understand your question 100%. I think you want to re-shuffle the row values so each column is sorted, right? Do you want something like this?

```
id | m_id | name | value
--------------------
 1 | 1    | bath |   2
 2 | 1    | bath |   3
 3 | 2    | bed  |   3
 3 | 2    | bed  |   4
```

where each column is sorted, but the rows don't make any sense anymore.

If so, I must inform you SQL cannot do this in any easy way. You are much better getting the data from the table using SQL and then rearrange it as you please using your custom programming language.

Comment: This would be equivalent to a table like `id | m_id | bath | bed`. In that case it will have two rows. and I can sort by `bath` or `bed` or both. It happens that my table is vertical. I could use something like ` ORDER BY FIELD (slug, 'bath')` .. For some reason I can't keep `m_id in order`

Comment: But, yeah, you're right, i might need to use some programing language to do further sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below order by clause in your query.
*order by decode(name,’bed’,1,’bath’,2), m_id*

Set asc,desc as per your needs.